# ReactJS - How to add in a removeEventListener when my mouse enters div element (onMouseEnter)

Tags: reactjs

**Question:** How can I have onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave disable then re-enable the onScroll function?

I've got a onScroll event listener that listens to the position of the current page. My issue is that I have a child div element that itself can be scrolled through.

Given my onScroll event is bounded to the parent div element, when I open the child element, and scroll through it, I get a undefined setState error.

I want to try and disable the onScroll event listener when I hover over the child div element.

My code (it's a very simplified to explain my issue):

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = () => this.listenToScroll()
}
listenToScroll() {
    // Does stuff with the value
}

render () {
    return (

        // This is the parent div element, which has a lot more text to cause the scroll effect
        <div onScroll={this.listenToScroll} >

        // This child element when clicked and expanded upon has an inner scroll element
        // When I scroll through the child element, I get a setState undefined error.
        <div>
            <ScrollExample 
                // This is what I want to happen, where when I enter this div element, the scroll event is disabled
                // When I exit it, it is re-enabled
                onMouseEnter={window.removeEventListener(this.listenToScroll, false)} 
                onMouseLeave={window.removeEventListener(this.listenToScroll, true)} 
            />
       </div>
       </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll)
}
listenToScroll() {
    // Does stuff with the value
}

render () {
    return (

        // This is the parent div element, which has a lot more text to cause the scroll effect
        <div onScroll={this.listenToScroll} >

        // This child element when clicked and expanded upon has an inner scroll element
        // When I scroll through the child element, I get a setState undefined error.
        <div>
            <ScrollExample 
                // This is what I want to happen, where when I enter this div element, the scroll event is disabled
                // When I exit it, it is re-enabled
                onMouseEnter={() => window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll)} 
                onMouseLeave={() => window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll)} 
            />
       </div>
       </div>
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for that Johnny.